# Alert Dialog Modifications

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog

I have made a Alert Dialog with two Edittext views.
Now i want to put imageView on it that imageview should show 4 Drawables and when you chose any from them it will load that selected Drawable in the ImageView

Now i don't know how i do that.

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Context context = this;
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    alert.setTitle("Shot On Logo Design");
    alert.setMessage("Shot On Logo");
    final EditText titleBox = new EditText(context);
    titleBox.setHint("Which Phone you are using");
    layout.addView(titleBox);

    final EditText descriptionBox = new EditText(context);
    descriptionBox.setHint("Who took the picture");
    layout.addView(descriptionBox);
    alert.setView(layout);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //What ever you want to do with the value
            //OR
            String YouEditTextValue2 = titleBox.getText().toString();

            shotText.setText("Shot on "+ YouEditTextValue2);

            String YouEditTextValue3 = descriptionBox.getText().toString();
            byText.setText("By: "+ YouEditTextValue3);


            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);


        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // what ever you want to do with No option.
        }
    });

    alert.show();
```

Comment: You should use a custom `DialogFragment`. This gives you the most control because you can create your own layouts.

Comment: Can you help me to make it ? @Barns52

Comment: It may help you i think   
             https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/android-alert-dialog-tutorial-working-time-picker-date-picker-list-dialogs/

Comment: How a single imageview will hold 4 Drwable

Comment: I want 4 Drawable to show on dialog and then if user select any one of them that selected should be loaded to ImageView.@Akashkumar

Answer (score 0):

This is a general implementation of a DialogFragment. You can change the following code any way you need-- even customize the layout as you wish. This is just an example of how you make and implement a custom `DialogFragment`.

Here is the code I use for a simple 'OK'/'Cancel' dialog. I find it quite flexible because you can create several similar dialogs for slightly different tasks. You will need to create a layout file - this gives you a great deal of flexibility on function and style.

My layout file is `fragment_ok_cancel_dialog`.

To satisfy your requirements just create your own layout file with all the elements in it you need (like your image).

In the Activity that calls the dialog you will need to implement the Listener.

```
implements OkCancelDialogFragment.OkCancelDialogListener
```

Another advantage is with my code you can change the title and the message to fit the needs of any Activity.

```
private void callMyDialog(){ 
    //Customize the title and message as needed
    String title = "This is my dialog title";
    String mess = "This is my dialog message";
    OkCancelDialogFragment dialog = OkCancelDialogFragment.newInstance(title, mess);
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "OkCancelDialogFragment2");
}
```

Now you need to implement the dialog callback in the Activity that calls the `DialogFragment`.

```
@Override
public void onFinishOkCancelDialog(boolean submit) {
    if(submit){
        // Do something positive
    }
    else{
        // Do something negative
    }
}
```

Now the code for the DialogFragment:

```
public class OkCancelDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

    Context context = null;

    private String title;
    private String message;
    private boolean submitData = false;

    private OkCancelDialogListener mListener;

    public OkCancelDialogFragment() {
    }

    public static OkCancelDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        OkCancelDialogFragment fragment = new OkCancelDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            title = getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE);
            message = getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveIntsanceState){

        context = getActivity();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ok_cancel_dialog, null, false);
        final TextView titleView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        final TextView messView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

        titleView.setText(title);
        messView.setText(message);

        builder.setView(rootView)
//                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button_dialog_title, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        submitData = true;
                        if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
                        mListener.onFinishOkCancelDialog(submitData);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        submitData = false;
                        if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
                        mListener.onFinishOkCancelDialog(submitData);
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OkCancelDialogListener {
        void onFinishOkCancelDialog(boolean submit);
    }

}
```

Please note that .setTitle(title) is valid for API 23 or higher (or maybe API 21 or higher?).